# Itunes 12.3.2.35 playlist order non-alphabetic

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, playlist

After updating iTunes to 12.3 something strange happened:

- When adding a new title or folder to my playlists it is added in the playlist view at the left as last item !
- When adding a title to the playlists and selecting a place, iTunes shows me as drop down an "alphabetic" list , why is this?

How can I synchronize the two views to alphabetic?

Comment: The problem is still present in version 12.3.3.17. Moral of software quality and updates: limit updates to when you have a real needed improvment provided by the version the seller wants you to test.

Answer (score 1):

Restart iTunes.

I have the same problem. After I create a playlist, the order of the playlists (in the sidebar) is sometimes not alphabetical. I suspect it's a bug. Restarting iTunes has always fixed it for me so far, though.

Comment: Thanks for your info ! I rebooted the Mac yesterday and afterwards found the items in iTunes in the right order ! It seems to be a bug !

Comment: I confirm it is a bug. The problem is still there on version 12.3.3.17.